# pentaho kettle mail job entry

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio

I have done a job adding the mail job entry step.I have configured the mail job entry correctly with the To and From addresses.In server tab given localhost and 25 port.I executed the job and it finished successfully.But no mail is delivered to inbox of the To or Cc address.Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the server use a commandline tool like "mail" to try sending a mail. Does that escape?  Suspect your server is not relaying email out to the real world.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the SMTP server and authentication details correctly. like for example,

- SMTP: smtp.emailsrvr.com
- Port: 25